# Find command for lookup up a directory tree

Tags: find

Is there any equivalent command, or options for, GNU `find` that will search up the directory tree?  I'd like to look backwards through the tree for files with a given name.  For example, say I'm in /usr/local/share/bin and I want to search look for a file called `foo`.  Ideally I'd like the command to look for the file in the following order:

1. /usr/local/share/bin/foo
2. /usr/local/share/foo
3. /usr/local/foo
4. /usr/foo
5. /foo

I know that I can write something like this as a shell function, but I was hoping there would be a command as rich as gnu `find` that I could leverage.

Comment: Have you tried find with the `-depth` option?  `-depth Process each directory's contents before the directory itself.`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `-depth` switch just changes the `find`'s mode of operation in terms of which directories it looks at first.  It doesn't appear to make `find` look upwards through the directory hierarchy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by upwards?  When doing a tree search you either do depth first, or breadth first.  A depth first search should return results like you describe above.

Comment: `find` looks downwards through the directory structure, towards the leaves of the file system.  I want to look upwards, meaning towards the root of the file system.  See the list in my original question.  Notice that it starts with a longer path (deeper in the file system) and moves towards towards short paths (shallower in the file system).

Comment: And how do you think a command could actually acomplish that?  The is no magical way for a command to know the deepest folder.  Are you going to pass the starting folder on the command line, or?

Comment: Precisely, when you run `find` you give it a starting path.  For what it's worth, I already implemented this in elisp the other day.  I was just hoping I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Consider re-wording your question and posting your solution.  I get what you are saying in the comments, but as written `-depth` precisely answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `find` and would still search from the root directory down to the current directory, but would only look inside the directories on that single path:

```
find / -exec bash -c '[[ $PWD != "$1"* ]]' bash {} \; -prune -name foo -print
```

The first part of the command, up to the `-prune`, will determine whether the current pathname being examined is located in the `$PWD` path.  It is pruned from the search path if it's not on the way to the current directory.

The comparison is carried out by a *very* short `bash` script that tests whether the current directory, `$PWD`, matches the start of the current pathname.

The bit after `-prune` tries to match `foo` against the filename that is being examined.

Example:  Trying to find something called `bin` somewhere in the directory structure above where I'm currently at.

```bsh
$ pwd
/home/kk/local/build/ast/build/src/cmd/ksh93/sh
```

```bsh
$ find / -exec bash -c '[[ $PWD/ != "${1%/}/"* ]]' bash {} \; -prune -name bin -print
/bin
/home/kk/local/bin
/home/kk/local/build/ast/bin
```

The manipulations of the values of `$PWD` and `$1` in the in-line script make sure that `$1` (the thing found by `find`) can be detected as a complete directory component at the start of `$PWD`, and not just as a prefix string (so that `/home/mat` is not confused with, e.g., `/home/matthew`).

---

On systems without `bash`, or where there is a faster-to-start `sh` shell:

```bsh
find / -exec sh -c 'case $PWD/ in ("${1%/}/"*) exit 1; esac' sh {} \; -prune -name bin -print
```

Comment: This post is excellent, an eye-opener, but I can't seem to `find` a web resource covering these kind of constructs. Any pointers?

Comment: @bu5hman I have never read a tutorial on how to use `find`. I have, however, used it a lot and read its manual. I'm sorry, but I don't have a magic web site for you.  Oh, yes I have... Continue answering questions here, and read other people's answers :-)

Comment: would I be right in understanding that an `-exec` can be inserted after any option to process the output at that stage of the search, to control what is passed to the next option?

Comment: @bu5hman Yes, exactly.  I did write a sort of "canonical answer" on the use of `find ... -exec ...`.  See [Understanding the -exec option of \`find\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705)

Comment: we are not worthy....

Comment: This can report false positives in directories that are a prefix of `$PWD` but not an ancestor of `$PWD`; for example, the example query would incorrectly print `/h/bin` if such a file existed.

Comment: @DanielWagner You can fix that by replacing `$1` by `${1%/}/` in the code. But I'm sure that leave some corner case open that I don't spot immediately.

Comment: @Kusalananda In my test, that doesn't seem to detect the file if it's in the current directory.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, good, that just means you need `/` at the end of `$PWD` as well. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_backwards () {
  test $# -ne 1 && return 2
  if [ -z "$find_backwards_recurse" ]; then
    pushd . &>/dev/null
    find_backwards_recurse=yes
  fi
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "${PWD}/${1}"
    popd &>/dev/null
    find_backwards_recurse=
    return 0
  else
    if [ / != "$PWD" ]; then
      cd ..
      find_backwards "$1"
    else
      popd &>/dev/null
      find_backwards_recurse=
      return 1
    fi
  fi
}

start cmd:> pwd
/home/hl/tmp/tmp

start cmd:> find_backwards foo
/home/hl/tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any command who would do that.

One possible script implementation.
rfind:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$1
[[ -f  "$d/$2" ]] && echo  "$d/$2" 
until  [[ ${d%%*/*} ]] || [[ -z  "$d"  ]]
do
   d=${d%/*}
   [[ -f  "$d/$2" ]] && echo  "$d/$2" 
done
```

Usage `rfind path filename`

Answer (score 0):

Walking up the directory path

```
f=/home/bu5hman/test; file=${f##*/}; base=${f%/*}
while [ ! -z $base ]; do
    find $base -maxdepth 1 -name $file
    base=${base%/*}
done
```