# Why is my perl regex in my bash script not working? MacOS Terminal

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression, perl, ls

I'm trying to move away from AppleScripts for workflows at my job, and create something simpler that can run in the background instead. For this task, I am given 35-40 files (5 renditions of 7 or 8 files at different qualities) every night, and I need to extract a part of the filename.

As an example, here's what one (abbreviated) batch of those files might look:

Each file has 5 renditions

```
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_640x360_1000.jpg
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_768x432_3000.jpg
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_960x540_5000.jpg
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_1280x720_7000.jpg
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_1920x1080_9000.jpg
```

And the files are all named as such (using the highest rendition, I'll get to why in a second):

```
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_02_dest_yyyyyyyyyy_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_03_dest_zzzzzzzzzz_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part1_aaaaaaaaaa_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part2_bbbbbbbbbb_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part3_special_cccccccccc_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part4_dddddddddd_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_04_dest_special_eeeeeeeeee_1920x1080_9000.jpg
```

So my goal is to use the `9000` part of the filename to grep only the highest rendition of each (it takes the longest to copy over, so if it's there, the rest of the files are there too), and then extract everything up to the second to last `_`. So far, I've been able to do part one, but not part 2.

When I do this, I am able to get a list of only the highest rendition:

```
    $ ls | grep 9000
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_02_dest_yyyyyyyyyy_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_03_dest_zzzzzzzzzz_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part1_aaaaaaaaaa_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part2_bbbbbbbbbb_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part3_special_cccccccccc_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_part4_dddddddddd_1920x1080_9000.jpg
    ab_12_345_04_dest_special_eeeeeeeeee_1920x1080_9000.jpg
```

Then I tried `ls | grep 9000 | perl -pe '/^.+(?=_.+_.+)/mg` thinking I'd get the following (based on what every online RegEx tester, and specifically, Perl RegEx testers I could find said would work):

```
    $ ls | grep 9000 | perl -pe '/^.+(?=_.+_.+)/mg`
    ab_12_345_01_dest_xxxxxxxxxx
    ab_12_345_02_dest_yyyyyyyyyy
    ab_12_345_03_dest_zzzzzzzzzz
    ab_12_345_part1_aaaaaaaaaa
    ab_12_345_part2_bbbbbbbbbb
    ab_12_345_part3_special_cccccccccc
    ab_12_345_part4_dddddddddd
    ab_12_345_04_dest_special_eeeeeeeeee
```

However, I got the same result as if I never even piped to perl. I originally tried implementing this with awk, but the command I was typing was getting pretty length and I figured RegEx might be the way to go. However, I need the positive lookahead in order to get it to stop matching at the second to last `_` (rather than a `_` counted from the beginning of the string), and awk was preserving the final `__` when I set `{$NL=$(NL-1)=""; print $0}`.

Comment: What is that expression supposed to be doing? You're matching something... and then what? You're not doing anything with the match.

Comment: Eventually, it's going to print to a text file on my desktop. I haven't gotten that far yet, I'm building it piece by piece. I need to get the strings to cut down correctly, then I need to sort them so that the 4 "part" titles go to the top of the list, and finally, print that to a text file on my desktop.

Comment: So... what you want is `s/^.+(?=_.+_.+)/$1/`?

Comment: @muru's recommendation only gave me the "_1920x1080_9000.jpg" part of the string

Comment: @AlexTorma well, at least now you know how to remove parts of the string. Now add brackets or use `$&` accordingly.

Comment: And I'm back to square 1, because `s/(^.+)(_.+_.+)/$1` prints the whole string.

Comment: @alex `ls | grep 9000 | perl -pe '/^.+(?=_.+_.+)/mg'` something is "wrong" here: you are using **perl on a directory like sed on file!** That data-mining-in-filenames screwed everything up in your step by step approach. Go back to square 0, not just one. Or to square one, but slightly different direction (away from the corner you are in now)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the actual task is here. You say you want a specific part of the name of one of the files? Which part? Which file? What do you want to do with it in the end?  Don't use line-based text-editing tools on filenames.

Answer (score 1):

With your `perl` command, you always print the line because you have `-p` option. The match part doesn't do anything.

You want `-n` and print the matching part:

```
ls -1 *9000.jpg \
| perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(.+)(?=_.+_.+)/'
```

As filenames may have newlines, you should modify this to read zero-delimited filenames although, in your case that may not be needed:

```
printf '%s\0' *9000.jpg \
| perl -lne 'INIT{ $/ = "\0"}; print $1 if /^(.+)(?=_.+_.+)/'
```

---

Alternatively, read the file names in a for-loop, then you can use shell only paramater expansion:

```
for f in *9000.jpg; do printf '%s\n' "${f%_*_*}"; done
```

This may be better suited for your task. (=> "Don't use line-based text-editing tools on filenames." @Kusalananda)

Comment: And why not `perl ... *9000.jpg` directly? Give the globlist directly? Either your last one, or some `partial_f_name.pl *9000.jpg >9.txt` call. I think the usual "Dont use..." rule does not apply here, because the info really is in the filenames this time. Bad luck/design. Nobody is grepping "9000".

Comment: `perl ... *9000.jpg` will read the contents of the files, not the filenames.

Comment: so I used ... and an alternative. I know, and I feel that exactly is the problem here. The sooner we get rid of the connection to contents, the easier. Is it not possible to loop through the arguments, which are first just names? In your printf loop you are ready to access file content of $f, but that is not needed here. Insted of `every file...every line` (*, then <>), it is just `every file...only the name` as string. You combine it well in that alternative, but what if it surpasses possibilities of `$(f...)` ? back to start!

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: why is this Q so "difficult" and needs `"${f%_*_*}"` or even `-exec sh -c 'blah blah' sh {} \; `  ? I was talking about your last alternative. I think it is best so far. But I don't know what the `=>` operator means pointing at kusa's mantra.

Comment: perl/sed/awk are line-based text-editing tools. Editing filenames with these is difficult because filenames are allowed to have newline character, you have to consider this. Otherwise these tools may fail.

Comment: "...will fail." Failure is when you `cp $(perl ...)`, not `echo $(perl ...)`. Or `cp my file todir` and not `echo my file todir` I simply ask myself: with that data in a file instead a listing: it would be nice and easy.

Comment: @pLumo, that first sentence should read "you always print the line _regardless of if_ it matches your regex", because that's what `-p` does, it prints `$_` after running the script. And the match doesn't do anything. Also, instead of `/.../; print $1`, I'd use `print $1 if /.../`, because otherwise it'll print something on _each_ line, and `$1` can contain values from the previous match (if the current line didn't match).

Comment: thanks a lot for your hints, edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pipe from `ls` to `grep` to filter your file list you can just

```
ls *9000.jpg
```

Also with your `grep` it will pick out any files that happen to have 9000 elsewhere in the name.

There is no issue with your regex, only with the `perl`. Use `grep` and you get what you want

```
ls *9000.jpg | grep -Po "^.+(?=_.+_.+)"
```

An alternative way of doing this could be

```
find . -iname "*9000.jpg" -exec sh -c 'basename ${1%_*_*}' sh {} \;
```

the `find` does the same as `ls`

The expansion `${1%_*_*}` strips the characters from the 2nd last `_` until the end of the string and `basename` removes the file path which `find` includes in its results.

The construct

```
-exec sh -c `blah blah` sh {} \;
```

is well worth learning to use with `find` and @Kusalananda has a good post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127537/find-command-for-lookup-up-a-directory-tree/523585#comment968191_523585)

`-exec` just tells `find` to do 'blah blah' with its output, `\;` means do the 'blah blah' with each result individually, `sh -c 'put some script in here'` is what you want to do with the results and finally `sh {}` passes the output from `find` back to the script defined in `sh -c`

Comment: So with your adventurous find "one liner": it does the job, or it needs processing? Because if yes, then better work on `ls *9000.jpg`'s output to a file from the start. No matter if it was you who downvoted me: I feel confirmed, see my answer if you haven't yet.

Comment: The linked Q is about needing find. Here you need only `ls` with glob `*`.

Comment: @rastafile I didn't downvote anyone....

Comment: thanks for answering. I thought there was an additional processing step involved. That is why I insisted on a file, and why I ask you if your solution is finished or not. Sorry.

Comment: This was my solution, and somehow it is true: "Start with ls -f *9000.jpg >resol9000.txt, then you can work on these lines like a normal human being." Rest was my confusion.